# Splitting random effects by group with lme4

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I am comparing two groups of participants change and magnitude of prediction errors over 60 trials. Each participant is completing the task based on two different learning profile types (learn_prof). Additionally, there is within-subject variation in the task (condition). When comparing the two groups variance of prediction errors with the Fligner-Killeen Test, I found the groups were significantly different. My model initially appears like the one below; however, I don't know if this accounts for the different variances between groups.

```
TD_PE_analysis1 <- lmer(PE ~  learn_prof * trial * condition + (1|subject) + (1|image), data=td_pref_all)
```

A sample of my associated data is below:

```
structure(list(subject = c("61086f515114c26363323a17", "6090919e35432ed7cf716ca4", 
"5dc797a6a4cc4255f8ea588e", "5f9b014daee4da2af5391e54", "5f2226ed22f0956bf55ddb71", 
"5dcc1eb66f3f168a9515c150", "5ac8f79068b65b00018d7ef9", "CC_86", 
"610455c1ee6fdb0b18a4bcf2", "5e363f622dd2885f05d43978", "62a21304a03b371374d3bea2", 
"5f3c48bea714e02094c9d0ae", "6282571cf39cd89341a474e9", "610881055b4f5daa95c3118c", 
"5f2853a8e736e613955f73bf", "5d3fc2a0bb27940001db4067", "60ae256eb7d66c5f70d02814", 
"5f70c532da8e516a8ccca1da", "5ac8f79068b65b00018d7ef9", "5f9e40344dbd1f3ea731975d"
), age = c(19L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 18L, 22L, 21L, 18L, 20L, 20L, 
21L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 21L), sex = c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), race = c("4", "5", "5", "4", "5", "5", "2", "5", 
"4", "5", "2", "2", "6", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "2", "5"), 
    bapq = c(3.97222222, 3.861111111, 3.666666667, 3.444444444, 
    2.444444444, 2.888888889, 2.444444444, 2.47222222, 3.055555556, 
    3.194444444, 3.777777778, 3.944444444, 3.38888889, 3.75, 
    4.027777778, 3.111111111, 3.305555556, 3.5, 2.444444444, 
    3.277777778), event = c(75L, 80L, 50L, 23L, 103L, 57L, 25L, 
    12L, 48L, 63L, 32L, 77L, 63L, 40L, 115L, 96L, 15L, 47L, 88L, 
    67L), timestamp = c("7/1/22 14:47", "6/7/21 15:27", "11/16/20 22:42", 
    "6/7/21 15:21", "6/7/21 15:38", "11/24/20 14:22", "6/7/21 13:49", 
    "9/3/20 18:40", "7/1/22 14:33", "11/16/20 19:11", "6/30/22 20:03", 
    "11/16/20 18:58", "7/1/22 14:53", "7/1/22 16:31", "6/7/21 15:27", 
    "6/7/21 15:31", "6/7/21 15:14", "7/1/22 13:25", "6/7/21 14:00", 
    "11/16/20 20:25"), condition = c("odd", "odd", "mean", "odd", 
    "mean", "odd", "mean", "odd", "mean", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
    "mean", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "mean", "odd", "mean"
    ), rating = c(3, 2, 4, 6, 4, 3, 6, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 
    5, 3, 4, 6, 5), rt_ms = c(1446, 2414, 1106, 2371, 3292, 1076, 
    4996, 2328, 2215, 1345, 1399, 1710, 1562, 1847, 1881, 2009, 
    1894, 1810, 3336, 1329), image = c("radio_1", "bagel_2", 
    "chocolate5", "pie1", "kiwi_01", "beads_2", "drums_1", "bacon_01", 
    "chess_2", "candy_3", "muffin3", "piano_2", "bike_01", "camera_1", 
    "berries_01", "grilled_cheese_01", "notebook_3", "cookie4", 
    "ball_02", "drums_1"), trial = c(14L, 19L, 49L, 22L, 42L, 
    56L, 24L, 11L, 47L, 2L, 31L, 16L, 2L, 39L, 54L, 35L, 14L, 
    46L, 27L, 6L), onset_s = c(660.204, 682.005, 369.298, 185.31, 
    966.195, 459.121, 204.844, 97.076, 378.956, 566, 228.529, 
    703.03, 684.207, 298.489, 838.409, 796.401, 111.799, 366.679, 
    844.903, 745.011), profile_rating = c(3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 3L
    ), block = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), sub_num = c(94L, 29L, 
    129L, 37L, 42L, 174L, 5L, 25L, 87L, 21L, 56L, 7L, 96L, 109L, 
    26L, 36L, 25L, 70L, 5L, 111L), own_pref = c(2L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 
    5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
    4L), item_num = c(128L, 18L, 49L, 123L, 93L, 17L, 69L, 9L, 
    53L, 38L, 102L, 97L, 28L, 46L, 25L, 82L, 111L, 61L, 20L, 
    57L), cat1 = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L), cat2 = c(2L, 11L, 12L, 
    12L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 11L, 
    1L, 12L, 3L, 2L), profile_rating_new = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
    2L), PE = c(1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2, 2, 0, 
    2, 0, 0, 3, 3), PE_si = c(1, -1, 2, 5, 2, 0, 3, 1, -2, 0, 
    3, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3), pro_PE = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L), mean_p1 = c(3.065789474, 4.197368421, 4.266447368, 3.914473684, 
    4.233552632, 3.006578947, 3.75, 4.213815789, 3.5, 4.404605263, 
    4.296052632, 4.4375, 4.240131579, 4.164473684, 4.398026316, 
    4.430921053, 2.927631579, 4.891089109, 3.713815789, 3.75), 
    mean_p2 = c(2.783950617, 3.878787879, 4.185185185, 3.771428571, 
    3.950617284, 2.691358025, 3.771604938, 4.484848485, 3.580246914, 
    4.475308642, 4.484848485, 3.757575758, 4.135802469, 3.666666667, 
    4.136363636, 4.057142857, 2.971428571, 4.777777778, 3.818181818, 
    3.771604938), mean_p3 = c(2.989399293, 3.703180212, 4.498233216, 
    3.858657244, 3.459363958, 3.261484099, 3.692579505, 4.689045936, 
    3.568904594, 4.971731449, 4.469964664, 3.989399293, 4.169611307, 
    3.971731449, 3.922261484, 4.243816254, 3.409893993, 5.148409894, 
    3.561837456, 3.692579505), med_p = c(3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 
    4, 4, 5, 4.5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4), own_pref_NaN = c(2, 
    5, 2, 6, 5, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 5, 2, 4), 
    learn_prof = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), learn_prof1 = c("asd", 
    "asd", "td", "asd", "asd", "td", "asd", "td", "asd", "td", 
    "asd", "td", "asd", "asd", "asd", "asd", "asd", "asd", "asd", 
    "td")), row.names = c(12463L, 17892L, 3289L, 16538L, 14597L, 
3377L, 12537L, 489L, 20682L, 3998L, 22643L, 8497L, 12141L, 20915L, 
14658L, 12907L, 18807L, 15890L, 12494L, 10977L), class = "data.frame")
```

Upon speaking with my advisor and reviewing an [article](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/2041-210X.13434) about the robustness of linear mixed effects models, I am not entirely sure if my model is sufficient as is or whether I need additional specifications. I am also wondering if my random effects make sense given the differences between my groups. This has been a thorn in my side so any suggestions would be very helpful!

Comment: It's a while since I've done this, but in my memory it's easier in nlme::lme() than in lme4::lmer().

Comment: I am not really super familiar with using nlme:lme(). With nlme, would I not have to use dummy variables? Prior posts on the topic have indicated lme4:lmer() would likely necessitate dummy variables. I'm assuming this would look something like ```(1|subject) + (1|image) + (1|dummygrp1) + (1|dummygrp2)```.  On an aside, I read a paper that LMMs are pretty robust to violations of assumptions including variance between groups. In this case, are any of these steps even necessary?

Comment: As an aside, it appears this is based on the previous question you posted about this. As I noted there, a significance test of variance doesn't really say all that much, at least without providing estimates of how much your groups differ. With a crossed effects model such as yours, you often obtain thousands of observations, as

$$
\text{total observations} = n_{\text{subjects}} \times n_{\text{images}}
$$

so 100 subs x 20 imgs gets you 2,000 obs. Thus even minor deviations in variance can be flagged when there are many observations. Consider this when doing a writeup on the results.

Comment: That's a really interesting point and indeed we have a ginormous data set so this could be a huge contributor.